# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When you try to run the query and see the error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5 Tell me how to fix

```
CREATE FUNCTION CreateGroup(GroupName VARCHAR(50), GroupIcon TEXT, GroupDescription VARCHAR(130), GroupCreator INT)
  RETURNS int(11)
  DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE groupID INT;
  INSERT INTO groups (name, icon, description) VALUES (GroupName, GroupIcon, GroupDescription);
  SET groupID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  INSERT INTO group_members VALUES (groupID, GroupCreator);
  RETURN groupID;
END;
CREATE FUNCTION AddMessage(r VARCHAR(255), s INT, t INT, m VARCHAR(255), creation DATETIME)
  RETURNS int(11)
  DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
        DECLARE lastID INT;
        DECLARE receiver INT;
        SELECT id INTO receiver from users WHERE username=r;
        INSERT INTO messages (receiver_id, sender_id, msg_type, message, created_At) values(receiver, s, t, m, creation);
        SET lastID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        INSERT INTO messages_receipt (message_id, user_id, is_delivered) VALUES (lastID, receiver, 0);
        RETURN lastID;
END;

CREATE FUNCTION AddGroupMessage(gid INT, s INT, t INT, m VARCHAR(255), creation DATETIME)
  RETURNS int(11)
  DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE lastID INT; DECLARE rowCount INT;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rowCount FROM group_members WHERE user_id = s AND group_id = gid;
  IF rowCount = 1 THEN
  INSERT INTO group_messages (group_id, user_id, msg_type, message, created_at) VALUES (gid, s, t, m, creation);
  SET lastID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  INSERT INTO group_receipt (message_id, user_id, is_delivered) SELECT gm.message_id, gmembers.user_id, 0 FROM
  group_messages gm LEFT JOIN group_members gmembers ON gmembers.group_id = gm.group_id WHERE gm.group_id = gid AND gm.message_id = lastID AND NOT gmembers.user_id = s;
  RETURN lastID;
  ELSE
    return 0;
  END IF;
END;

CREATE DEFINER = 'inikspbh_weeki'@'localhost'
FUNCTION AddGroupMember(GroupID INT, MemberName VARCHAR(255), Username INT)
  RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO group_members VALUES (GroupID, MemberName);
  RETURN 1;
END;
```

Comment: use php terms with single quotes on referring to varchar datatype terms

Comment: Did you change the DELIMITER?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `delimiter` to separate the creates of the functions

```
       DELIMITER $$ 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `CreateGroup` $$ 
CREATE FUNCTION CreateGroup(GroupName VARCHAR(50), GroupIcon TEXT, GroupDescription VARCHAR(130), GroupCreator INT)
  RETURNS int(11)
  DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE groupID INT;
  INSERT INTO groups (name, icon, description) VALUES (GroupName, GroupIcon, GroupDescription);
  SET groupID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  INSERT INTO group_members VALUES (groupID, GroupCreator);
  RETURN groupID;
END;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `AddMessage` $$ 
CREATE FUNCTION AddMessage(r VARCHAR(255), s INT, t INT, m VARCHAR(255), creation DATETIME)
  RETURNS int(11)
  DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
        DECLARE lastID INT;
        DECLARE receiver INT;
        SELECT id INTO receiver from users WHERE username=r;
        INSERT INTO messages (receiver_id, sender_id, msg_type, message, created_At) values(receiver, s, t, m, creation);
        SET lastID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        INSERT INTO messages_receipt (message_id, user_id, is_delivered) VALUES (lastID, receiver, 0);
        RETURN lastID;
END;$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `AddGroupMessage` $$ 
CREATE FUNCTION AddGroupMessage(gid INT, s INT, t INT, m VARCHAR(255), creation DATETIME)
  RETURNS int(11)
  DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE lastID INT; DECLARE rowCount INT;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rowCount FROM group_members WHERE user_id = s AND group_id = gid;
  IF rowCount = 1 THEN
  INSERT INTO group_messages (group_id, user_id, msg_type, message, created_at) VALUES (gid, s, t, m, creation);
  SET lastID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  INSERT INTO group_receipt (message_id, user_id, is_delivered) SELECT gm.message_id, gmembers.user_id, 0 FROM
  group_messages gm LEFT JOIN group_members gmembers ON gmembers.group_id = gm.group_id WHERE gm.group_id = gid AND gm.message_id = lastID AND NOT gmembers.user_id = s;
  RETURN lastID;
  ELSE
    return 0;
  END IF;
END;$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `AddGroupMember` $$ 
CREATE DEFINER = 'inikspbh_weeki'@'localhost' FUNCTION AddGroupMember(GroupID INT, MemberName VARCHAR(255), Username INT)
  RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO group_members VALUES (GroupID, MemberName);
  RETURN 1;
END;$$
delimiter ;
```